# Subquery in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Does anyone know the changes needed to this code to get the count of the unique instances of DistinctThings instead of just the count? At the moment when I run the code I just get the count. DistinctThings are in col f1.

So what I was trying to achieve is a list of three cols, with the unique dates (col f15), then the count of the distinct things (col f1) then the sum of the values (col f16)

Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT f15, sum(f16), Count(*) AS DistinctThings
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT f1, f15, f16 FROM Table)
group by f15
;
```

Dummy data:

```
F1       F15           F16
Bob     01/12/2017     100
Harry   02/12/2017     200
James   03/12/2017     300
Bob     01/12/2017     100
Harry   02/12/2017     200
James   03/12/2017     300
Bob     01/12/2017     100
Harry   02/12/2017     200
James   03/12/2017     300

Sam     04/12/2017     400
Bob     01/12/2017     17
Harry   02/12/2017     68
James   03/12/2017     33
Sam     04/12/2017      4
Bob     01/12/2017     13
Harry   02/12/2017     234
James   03/12/2017     324
Sam     04/12/2017     57
```

Result I get when I run the query:

```
f15     DistinctThings   Total

01/12/2017      1            216.5
02/12/2017      1            214.5
03/12/2017      1            209.5
04/12/2017      1            172.5
```

So the total is col f16 and I would like DistinctThings to be the count of the distinct number of names per distinct date

Comment: Please provide few rows of sample data, current results, and desired results to better illustrate your issue.

Comment: Hi Parfait, I have added some sample data and the results I get when I run the statement provided by Gustav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
SELECT 
    f15, 
    Count(*) As DistinctThings,
    Sum(s16) As Total
FROM 
    (SELECT f15, Sum(f16) As s16 FROM Table Group By f15)
group by 
    f15
```

**Edit**:

Try this subquery:

```
    (SELECT f15, Sum(f16) As s16 FROM Table Group By f15, f1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it returns the count of f1 as 1 for everything. Do you know how I can include the count of the distinct values in f1 as well? So what I am trying to get are the distinct dates (f15), the count of the distinct items for those dates (f1) and the total values (sum f16) for those dates?

Comment: It groups by f15 so it counts the distinct count per f15. There is no f1.

Comment: So can the statement be amended to also include the count of distinct values in f1? Will provide dummy data soon too.and the results I'm getting

Comment: I added in my data, do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: My query should return those results. You have only one person per date.

Comment: Apologies that was my mistake - I do have multiple people per date, I have amended the sample data, but the satement still only returns 1. Do you know why this is? Does there need to be another subquery for the count of distinct people?

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly and sorry for dragging out the process.

Comment: No problem. Glad you succeeded!